# DKIM fails at reply to email

Tags: postfix, dkim

i have a problem with dkim and reply to an email. If i send a email to google everthing is OK:

```
   Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@klh.de;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of xx.xxx@klh.de designates 213.214.14.217 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xx.xxx@klh.de;
   dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=klh.de
   Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by mx.klh.de (Postfix) with ESMTP id 21328124736 for <xxx@gmail.com>; Fri, 13 Jan 2017 11:14:34 +0100 (CET)
   DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=klh.de; s=201611; t=1484302474; bh=/PcOn/Jx9dciEPOjrIgSPkSriQjwDzxCFVJSYG0Twe4=; h=Date:From:To:Subject:References:In-Reply-To:From; b=mOMITyTzK7VS2pkJtlpF1hkN1ZK94MfVri+bpbQ3iaglhWtIzbK54T/d1oFI377rZ
 3CUgdBPITu//iWvLM+nXacCt9PA68o4aKiZJ/ROue3OBBKe2Hsv7hViYbrWWmedeVx
 AKAIgcm/MLtfWjCXqta2EF93KAG2PbQC65uoZMyA=
```

but if i answer to an email send originally from a google user the dkim failed:

```
   Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=fail header.i=@klh.de;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of xx.xxx@klh.de designates 213.214.14.217 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xx.xxx@klh.de;
   dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=klh.de
   Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by mx.klh.de (Postfix) with ESMTP id 401451201B6 for <xxxx@gmail.com>; Fri, 13 Jan 2017 10:52:36 +0100 (CET)
  DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=klh.de; s=201611; t=1484301156; bh=nQbpY6Q0JdxvJ9ALEm7aToUJOYq5u0rDOOKM7egvk+s=; h=Date:From:To:Subject:References:In-Reply-To:From; b=U2Hs92VT0XeogRtMZnG7ME5wrXsykq8v5yOwfdAgCNhC+Bnd+K7kdPLT/NizVg2AI
 gY97ArCjm8jIdk6XsAmBdEWj/HXVYp3ELOTOBv1MqdPp/jqQl2TdyZEZ8YXwgyR1+4
 3oKLfQ3J7Ro0o5PiLr2CFrxjm9DuWAorvSiH4m2A=
```

This only occurs when i reply to an email that communication i haven't started. If i send a email and the google user replies and i answer to this email everthing is fine and dkim pass.

Comment: opendkim is v2.10.3.

The only thing that helps is when I change 
Canonicalization    relaxed/simple to Canonicalization    simple/simple
I have no idea why this works, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Great you've pinpointed a repeatable scenario. Just cc the email to multiple free DKIM testing addresses (as you send it to google expecting a fail) and hopefully one of them will give you some clue.

Also update `opendkim` to the most recent version to rule multiple bugs already fixed.